# Set dynamic inline style angular 2 not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have a small issue... I have a div within that I want to apply an inline style like so:

```
div style="background: url(..{{config.general.image}})"></div
```

The bad part is that it worked in beta 16 but since I upgrade to RC1 it doesn't.. and for that matter [style.background] doesn't work either.. But if I output {{config.general.image}} in the class tag or anywhere in the template it works.

Is this a bug or did something change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngStyle` should be used instead

```
<div [ngStyle]="{background: 'url(' + config.general.image + ')'}">
```

Comment: Think I tried that even with red color and it dosen t work.. also does in work in the template - separate file to do that ?

Comment: Sorry I missed the curly braces.

Comment: Hmm i will try this.. tnx for the answer